# check if specific file inputs are submitted with the form using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a form with some dynamic file inputs. the name of the input files are set using a counter.

```
$("#addCompanionBtn").click(function(){
    counter++;
    var CompanionFields = '<input class="form-control" name="com_photo_'+counter+'" type="file" />';
    $('#companionsDiv').after(CompanionFields);
});
```

I am using PHP to process the form. How am i supposed to check if a file is submitted with the form or not!!?
Since the up to 10 files can be uploaded with the form, it is not a rational approach to check files as bellow:

```
if(isset($_FILES['com_photo_1']) or isset($_FILES['com_photo_2'])){...}
```

Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: suggest to use separate hidden element with some value. and in PHP check the availability of element and correct value

Comment: Try using the name as `com_photo[]` this will send files as an array.

Comment: I have already tried `com_photo[]` but since each input file is already an array in PHP, i could not come up with a good idea to organize them for saving!

Comment: That is exactly the approach to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JQuery**

```
$("#addCompanionBtn").click(function(){
    var CompanionFields = '<input class="form-control" name="com_photo[]" type="file" />';
    $('#companionsDiv').after(CompanionFields);
});
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_FILES['com_photo'])){
    foreach($_FILES['com_photo'] as $photo){
        //Do Stuff here
    }
}
```